# Error:(66, 9) error: illegal start of expression

Tags: parse-platform

I want to use parse to get notification on my app but when i put the below code in Oncreate method i got some errors .Both are give below in images.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB6GS.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcqwh.jpg)

Comment: Is this in android? If so, add - android label.

Answer (score 0):

Change -

```
public void onCreate(){...}
```

To -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: @shubham shukla This maybe is not the only problem with your code, add please the code of your Activity.